# Java fluent builder and inheritance

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, fluent-interface

One more day and one more struggle with generics.

I have set of `Control` objects with the following inheritance tree:

```
BaseControl
|_SimpleControl
  |_MultipleControl
    |_AutocompleteControl
    |_SelectControl
```

For each of non-abstract object in this tree I'd like to provide builder so these objects can be created easily. Here is what I have so far:

BaseControlBuilder:

```
public abstract class BaseControlBuilder<C extends BaseControl, B extends BaseControlBuilder<C, B>> {
    protected C control;
    private B builder;

    BaseControlBuilder() {
        control = createObj();
        builder = getThis();
    }
    public C build() { return control; }

    protected abstract C createObj();
    protected abstract B getThis();
}
```

SimpleControlBuilder:

```
public class SimpleControlBuilder<C extends SimpleControl, B extends SimpleControlBuilder<C, B>>
        extends BaseControlBuilder<SimpleControl, SimpleControlBuilder<C, B>> {

    public SimpleControlBuilder(final String id, final String caption,
            final InputType controlType) {
        super();
        control.setId(id);
        control.setCaption(caption);
        control.setType(controlType);
    }

    public SimpleControlBuilder(final InputType controlType) {
        this("", "", controlType);
    }

    public SimpleControlBuilder(final Enum<?> en, final InputType controlType) {
        this(en.name(), en.toString(), controlType);
    }

    public SimpleControlBuilder<C, B> disabled() {
        control.setDisabled(true);
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    protected SimpleControl createObj() {
        return new SimpleControl();
    }

    @Override
    protected SimpleControlBuilder<C, B> getThis() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

MultipleControlBuilder:

```
abstract class MultipleControlBuilder<C extends MultipleControl, B extends MultipleControlBuilder<C, B>>
        extends SimpleControlBuilder<MultipleControl, MultipleControlBuilder<C, B>> {

    MultipleControlBuilder(final InputType type) {
        super(type);
    }

    MultipleControlBuilder(final String id, final String caption,
            final InputType type) {
        super(id, caption, type);
    }

    MultipleControlBuilder(final Enum<?> en, final InputType type) {
        super(en, type);
    }

    public MultipleControlBuilder<C, B> multiple() {
        ((MultipleControl) control).setMultiple(true);
        return this;
    }
}
```

AutocompleteControlBuilder:

```
public class AutocompleteControlBuilder<C extends AutocompleteControl, B extends AutocompleteControlBuilder<C, B>>
    extends MultipleControlBuilder<AutocompleteControl, AutocompleteControlBuilder<C, B>> {

    public AutocompleteControlBuilder(final String url,
            final AutocompleteType autocompleteType) {
        this("", "", url, autocompleteType);
    }

    public AutocompleteControlBuilder(final String id,
            final String caption, final String url,
            final AutocompleteType autocompleteType) {
        super(id, caption, InputType.AUTOCOMPLETE);
        ((AutocompleteControl) control).setAutocompleteUrl(url);
        ((AutocompleteControl) control).setAutocompleteType(autocompleteType);
    }

    public AutocompleteControlBuilder(final Enum<?> en, final String url,
            final AutocompleteType autocompleteType) {
        this(en.name(), en.toString(), url, autocompleteType);
    }

    @Override
    protected AutocompleteControl createObj() {
        return new AutocompleteControl();
    }

    @Override
    protected AutocompleteControlBuilder<C, B> getThis() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

But surprisingly I have got some unexpected results.
For instance, in the following code I have to cast `control` to `MultipleControl` to call setter despite the fact that `C extends MultipleControl`...

Moreover, the following `build()` method call: `new AutocompleteControlBuilder<AutocompleteControl, AutocompleteControlBuilder>("url", AutocompleteType.STANDARD).build());` returns `SimpleControl` instead of `AutocompleteControl` which doesn't make sense, cause I explicitly provided type parameter.

And the last straw is that conciseness and clear code I'm trying to achieve are killed by ugly `new AutocompleteControlBuilder<AutocompleteControl, AutocompleteControlBuilder>` constructor call. Could anybody point me to the best practices of solving this problem?

Comment: May I ask why you have the ```builder``` field? I don't see you using it. Java already has covariant returns types, at a first glance, I'd say you could remove both type parameters, since they both seem to be implementation details. It really depends on the use though...

Comment: I have a fast question about this setup @mr.nothing , do you actually need `SimpleControl` to be non-abstract?

Comment: Hmm, JavaFX started with builders too, and nowadays does without them. So builders _can_ have stylistic drawbacks. In your case: less constructors, a factory method in the control class itself (`RadioButton.create().label("not me").build():`)

Comment: @JornVernee, oh, you're right, this code is a little bit surplus. Will edit the question, thanks. Regarding the second parameter (control related) - how should I implement build method to return right control type?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce, yeah, this is how controls are organized.

Comment: @JoopEggen, Unfortunately, I don't have access to Control classes, they are autogenerated and are provided as some type of external dependency...

Comment: Aha, _when what you have is a pile of manure then grow roses._ Nobody will care about the substrata. And make something beautiful. One trick is to start top-down: make a form fluent API with composition too, and refine that to its components, moving some setters to ancestor classes.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, in order to set this up correctly, you should make some changes:

```
public class SimpleControlBuilder<C extends SimpleControl, B extends SimpleControlBuilder<C, B>>
        extends BaseControlBuilder<SimpleControl, SimpleControlBuilder<C, B>> { // this should extend with the extension classes

    public SimpleControlBuilder(final String id, final String caption,
            final InputType controlType) {
        super();
        control.setId(id);
        control.setCaption(caption);
        control.setType(controlType);
    }

    public SimpleControlBuilder(final InputType controlType) {
        this("", "", controlType);
    }

    public SimpleControlBuilder(final Enum<?> en, final InputType controlType) {
        this(en.name(), en.toString(), controlType);
    }

    public SimpleControlBuilder<C, B> disabled() { // this should return B
        control.setDisabled(true);
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    protected SimpleControl createObj() { // this should return C
        return new SimpleControl();
    }

    @Override
    protected SimpleControlBuilder<C, B> getThis() { // this should return B
        return this;
    }
}
```

So that means

```
public abstract class SimpleControlBuilder<C extends SimpleControl, B extends SimpleControlBuilder<C, B>>
        extends BaseControlBuilder<C, B> {

    public SimpleControlBuilder(final String id, final String caption,
            final InputType controlType) {
        super();
        control.setId(id);
        control.setCaption(caption);
        control.setType(controlType);
    }

    public SimpleControlBuilder(final InputType controlType) {
        this("", "", controlType);
    }

    public SimpleControlBuilder(final Enum<?> en, final InputType controlType) {
        this(en.name(), en.toString(), controlType);
    }

    public B disabled() {
        control.setDisabled(true);
        return getThis();
    }
}
```

And

```
abstract class MultipleControlBuilder<C extends MultipleControl, B extends MultipleControlBuilder<C, B>>
        extends SimpleControlBuilder<C, B> {

    MultipleControlBuilder(final InputType type) {
        super(type);
    }

    MultipleControlBuilder(final String id, final String caption,
            final InputType type) {
        super(id, caption, type);
    }

    MultipleControlBuilder(final Enum<?> en, final InputType type) {
        super(en, type);
    }

    public B multiple() {
        control.setMultiple(true);
        return getThis();
    }
}
```

And

```
public abstract class AutocompleteControlBuilder<C extends AutocompleteControl, B extends AutocompleteControlBuilder<C, B>>
    extends MultipleControlBuilder<C, B>> {

    public AutocompleteControlBuilder(final String url,
            final AutocompleteType autocompleteType) {
        this("", "", url, autocompleteType);
    }

    public AutocompleteControlBuilder(final String id,
            final String caption, final String url,
            final AutocompleteType autocompleteType) {
        super(id, caption, InputType.AUTOCOMPLETE);
        control.setAutocompleteUrl(url);
        control.setAutocompleteType(autocompleteType);
    }

    public AutocompleteControlBuilder(final Enum<?> en, final String url,
            final AutocompleteType autocompleteType) {
        this(en.name(), en.toString(), url, autocompleteType);
    }
}
```

This works if `MultipleControl extends SimpleControl` and `AutocompleteControl extends MultipleControl`, and you have concrete extensions of `SimpleControl` that can return themselves with `getThis()` with concretized parameters.

```
public class SomeControlBuilder extends MultipleControlBuilder<SomeControl, SomeControlBuilder> {
    public SomeControlBuilder(final InputType type) {
        super(type);
    }

    public SomeControlBuilder(final String id, final String caption,
            final InputType type) {
        super(id, caption, type);
    }

    public SomeControlBuilder(final Enum<?> en, final InputType type) {
        super(en, type);
    }

    @Override
    protected SomeControlBuilder getThis() {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    protected SomeControl createObj() {
        return new SomeControl();
    }
}
```

Comment: Am I gettings this right that there is no elegant way to solve this? There will be still terrible contructor calls with type parameters which can be *logically* omitted.

Comment: well I don't really know what those parameters do. You'll most likely need to retain the 3 constructors across the hierarchy if you retain those constructors, yes. I think the generics have been greatly simplified though, I think it's quite elegant.